# Linux RAID10 hit bad disk while re-syncing. Is it hosed?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, software-raid, smart, drive-failure

I have a Linux software RAID10 device on md0. It's made up of 4 1TB disks sd[abcd]. Yesterday Smart emailed me to say a disk was going bad (seek errors going up and reallocated sectors). I rebooted with a new drive and added it to the array. /proc/mdstat showed it was re-syncing. Sometime mid-morning, errors started flying about a "media error" on ANOTHER disk in the array. I checked /var/log/messages and saw a ton of *Emask 0x49 (media error)*  entries for another drive in the same array. Thanks Murphy.

I replaced the newly failed drive but no luck starting the array. mdadm also tells me sdc is busy. Anyone know why? That's the newest drive:

```
    # mdadm  -S /dev/md0
    mdadm: stopped /dev/md0

    # mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd -fv
    mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
    mdadm: /dev/sda is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
    mdadm: /dev/sdb is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot -1.
    mdadm: /dev/sdc is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot -1.
    mdadm: /dev/sdd is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
    mdadm: added /dev/sda to /dev/md0 as 1
    mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 2 of /dev/md0
    mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 3 of /dev/md0
    mdadm: added /dev/sdb to /dev/md0 as -1
    mdadm: failed to add /dev/sdc to /dev/md0: Device or resource busy
    mdadm: added /dev/sdd to /dev/md0 as 0
    mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives and 1 spare - not enough to start the array.

# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdd[4](S) sdb[6](S) sda[5](S)
      2930287104 blocks super 1.0

unused devices: <none>

# for d in a b c d; do mdadm -E /dev/sd$d; done
/dev/sda:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 24edfbfb:f97149e1:93e019e7:fc7b3f03
           Name : bach:0
  Creation Time : Thu Sep 30 13:50:40 2010
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1953524896 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 3907049472 (1863.03 GiB 2000.41 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953524736 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Super Offset : 1953525152 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : fc75bc5b:e32851bb:9725e0ce:aeaa1680

    Update Time : Thu Dec 27 09:28:13 2012
       Checksum : 3a03b8e1 - correct
         Events : 7314

         Layout : near=1, far=2
     Chunk Size : 256K

    Array Slot : 5 (failed, failed, failed, failed, 0, 1, failed)
   Array State : uU__ 5 failed


/dev/sdb:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 24edfbfb:f97149e1:93e019e7:fc7b3f03
           Name : bach:0
  Creation Time : Thu Sep 30 13:50:40 2010
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1953524896 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 3907049472 (1863.03 GiB 2000.41 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953524736 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Super Offset : 1953525152 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : adbb2437:931c08fc:0e5428b8:a6d0d47d

    Update Time : Thu Dec 27 09:28:13 2012
       Checksum : 3d2946ab - correct
         Events : 7306

         Layout : near=1, far=2
     Chunk Size : 256K

    Array Slot : 6 (failed, failed, failed, failed, 0, 1)
   Array State : uu__ 4 failed


/dev/sdc:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 24edfbfb:f97149e1:93e019e7:fc7b3f03
           Name : bach:0
  Creation Time : Thu Sep 30 13:50:40 2010
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1953524896 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 3907049472 (1863.03 GiB 2000.41 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953524736 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Super Offset : 1953525152 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 5c216a06:c17d4e4f:9dc5c09b:b3f7d72f

    Update Time : Thu Dec 27 09:28:13 2012
       Checksum : f5508998 - correct
         Events : 0

         Layout : near=1, far=2
     Chunk Size : 256K

    Array Slot : 6 (failed, failed, failed, failed, 0, 1)
   Array State : uu__ 4 failed


/dev/sdd:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.0
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : 24edfbfb:f97149e1:93e019e7:fc7b3f03
           Name : bach:0
  Creation Time : Thu Sep 30 13:50:40 2010
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 4

 Avail Dev Size : 1953524896 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 3907049472 (1863.03 GiB 2000.41 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953524736 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
   Super Offset : 1953525152 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 69a39c8f:0b25b888:0b4e1848:42aed006

    Update Time : Thu Dec 27 09:28:13 2012
       Checksum : 3b3d0e7c - correct
         Events : 7314

         Layout : near=1, far=2
     Chunk Size : 256K

    Array Slot : 4 (failed, failed, failed, failed, 0, 1, failed)
   Array State : Uu__ 5 failed
```

I've got backups of the array but it'll be a day a full day to restore. Any way to get this thing online?

Comment: Was the raid array entirely rebuilt before you inserted the second drive?

Comment: Eric -- no, not sure. It was at 37% at one point but beyond that would be sheer imagination.

Comment: If second hard drive failed before raid was rebuilt and was mirroring first hard drive info, then Murphy is evil and all you can do afaik is to use your backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a last ditch attempt, I tried re-creating the array with the newly failed disk and the mdadm `--assume-clean` option to see what it would do. It came up, but no data to be found. Eh well.. yay for backups.